# How can assign variable for giving style background color to the column

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to give the background color to the textbox conditionally but not working when I assign the variable columnstyle  to the textbox. Here  is the html code

```
var columnstyle = "text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00";
 if (Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected)
 {
       isdisabled = true;
      styleset = "background-color:#90EE90";
     columnstyle = "text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90";
 }
<td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs, new { @class = "form-control input-sm NormalHrsl", @style= "@(columnstyle)",  @Value = Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs, onchange = "CalculateTotal()" })
<td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this
var columnstyle = Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected == false ? "text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#FFBF00" : "text-align:center;vertical-align:central;background-color:#90EE90";

...

Comment: Then how can I use  variable columnstyle  with Html.TextBoxFor

Comment: In the same way you are currently using. I guess it will work